# Webware support for python 3

Tags: python, python-3.4

I have an old project which uses `web ware`, where i want to convert to *latest version 3.4*

I am wondering whether any webware is available for *python version 3.4*. What I am seeing is the *webware version 1.1.1* which is old and seems like it is not supporting the version 3.4 as I could see the print is written print `abc` and no braces.

So how should i approach converting this project which is based on *python 2.2.1* ?

Answer (score 0):

According to their [website](http://www.webwareforpython.org/Docs/Overview.html) they have no immediate plans to support Python 3.  If you really must convert your website to a Python 3 platform you should probably look at one of the frameworks that already supports Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

[Webware for Python 3](https://github.com/Cito/w4py3) is now available, which supports Python 3.6 and newer.